# Labels in SVM algorithm

Tags: svm

I am reading some ML books (Burkov's and Raschka's), and i have seen there, that for a binary classification problem using SVM, my "positive" label needs to be equal +1 and my "negative" label needs to be -1.

My dataset has labels equals to +1 and 0. Should i change all the 0 to -1? Or let's say I'm using Scikitlearn's SVC, will it automatically perform this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to change your y labels, sklearn will do this for you.